# Angularjs drag and drop event - Error: $compile:nodomevents

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, drag-and-drop

> #### Interpolations for HTML DOM event attributes are disallowed.  Please use the ng- versions (such as ng-click instead of onclick) instead.

i am new to angularJS. i am using below code which works in a sample application.

**html:**

```
<div id="noun" 
ondrop="drop(event)" 
ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

**js:**

```
    allowDrop= function (ev) {
        //console.log("In allow drop");
        ev.preventDefault();
    };


   drop=  function (ev) {
        console.log("In drop");
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

        if(ev.target.id =='verb' && $scope.verbs.indexOf(data) != -1){
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
        else{
            //alert(data + ' is not a ' + ev.target.id +'. Try again');
            console.log(data + ' is not a ' + ev.target.id +'. Try again');
        }

    };
```

However, when i use similar code in my real application, i am getting error as shown below.

> 16:47:39.246 angular.js:12783 Error: [$compile:nodomevents] Interpolations for HTML DOM event attributes are disallowed.  Please use the ng- versions (such as ng-click instead of onclick) instead.
>       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.10/$compile/nodomevents
>           at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
>           at attrInterpolatePreLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8940:25)
>           at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9079:9)
>           at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8545:11)
>           at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7965:13)
>           at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7968:13)
>           at nodeLinkFn .....(some more like this)..... `<p draggable="true" ondragend="addProcess({{level2.root_id}}, {{level2.parent_id}}, {{level2._id}})" class="ng-binding">`
>       (anonymous) @ angular.js:12783
>       (anonymous) @ angular.js:9535
>       invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:9081
>       nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8545
>       compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7965
>       compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7968
>       nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8561
>       compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7965
>       publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7845
>       boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7983
>       controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8593
>       ngRepeatAction @ angular.js:28080
>       $watchCollectionAction @ angular.js:16066
>       $digest @ angular.js:16203
>       $apply @ angular.js:16467
>       done @ angular.js:10852
>       completeRequest @ angular.js:11050
>       requestLoaded @ angular.js:10991

Similar error is repeated 12k+ times when page is loaded. my real application code is as below.

**html:**

In real application, the html code is as follows.

```
 <p ondragstart="dragStart(event)"
    ondragend="addProcess({{level2.root_id}}, {{level2.parent_id}}, {{level2._id}})"
    draggable="true" id="dragtarget">
 {{level2.name}}
</p>
```

**js:**

In java script file, i tried to use as both $scope.dropProcess and dropProcess too.

Still the error repeats thousands of times and i am not sure why.
Any inputs/suggestions to fix or understand this would be great help.

This is my first question here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In real application, the html code is as follows.

    <p     ondragstart="dragStart(event)" 
    ondragend="addProcess({{level2.root_id}}, {{level2.parent_id}}, {{level2._id}})" 
    draggable="true" id="dragtarget">
    {{level2.name}}</p>

Comment: have you included `drag-and-drop` related dependency in your module ?

Comment: share your full code and please share the same application link too

Comment: Hi Usman, Thanks. i am using native html5 drag and drop features. i am not using any drag drop library. The real code is very big. The code which is related to drag and drop is pasted above.

Comment: try changing `ondragend="addProcess({{level2.root_id}}, {{level2.parent_id}}, {{level2._id}})"` to `ondragend="addProcess(level2.root_id, level2.parent_id, level2._id)"`

Comment: It clearly states what is the problem, and it even gives a fix recommendation. Why won't you simply implement what the library recommends?

Comment: Hi Prokhorov, sorry  i am new to this and i could not understand what i should do despite trying different things for many days. can you please elaborate what i should try? I have no clue why ondragend works in sample application but not in real application and also why the nodommovement error comes 12k+ times.

Comment: You need to create a directive for this

Comment: Thanks Charlietfl. how it is working in sample application? should it not work there too if a directive is what is needed?

Comment: The problem is that you are using interpolation, `{{ }}`, in a global context. This exposes your application to security vulnerabilities like XSS.  See the explaination in [AngularJS Error Reference - Error: $compile:nodomevents
Interpolated Event Attributes](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nodomevents).